# Python installation fails in chroot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, virtual-machine, chroot

I tried to install `Miniconda` Python in a chroot:

```
chroot $1 wget -q https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-3.19.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -O /tmp/miniconda.sh                                                                                    
chroot $1 chmod +x /tmp/miniconda.sh
chroot $1 /tmp/miniconda.sh -f -b -p /opt/conda
```

But the installation is incomplete and I get:

```
opt/conda/pkgs/python-3.5.1-0/bin/python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.5m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

If I boot the finalized image and run the commands manually, it works **fine**. Is there some problem with the chroot commands?

**Update**

The chroot environment is created with `vmbuilder`, which uses `debootstrap` afaik:

```
vmbuilder kvm ubuntu -o -v --suite precise --arch amd64 --rootsize 9216 --user username --pass password --hostname $dname --addpkg libjson-perl --addpkg liburi-encode-perl --addpkg curl --addpkg acpid --addpkg openssh-server --addpkg wordpress --addpkg memcached --addpkg php5-memcache --addpkg nfs-common --addpkg dmidecode --addpkg unzip --addpkg mysql-server --addpkg libstring-shellquote-perl --tmpfs - --domain mydomain.com --ip 10.1.1.2 --execscript="./$me"
```

Comment: Please tell us how you created and populated the `chroot` environment. Did you use `debootstrap` or similar, for example? Something might be missing from there.

Comment: @Celada I have updated the question. AFAIK `vmbuilder` uses `debootstrap`.